# Jenkins - triggered builds on all Nodes

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Currently, we have two machines. One has Jenkins installed and is hosted as master in Jenkins and another one is Slave. Number of executors for both Nodes are set to 1.

I am not exactly sure how Jenkins work behind the scenes but currently when I triggered 2 build jobs simultaneously, it somehow runs only on slave node (and put another build job in queue), if I disconnect the slave and leave only master, then it would run on master(and put another build job in queue).

How to configure Jenkins so that it leverage all my available nodes (master and slave). In other words, I would like to have all available nodes consumes the queue and not just for one of the Nodes.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you need to enable `Execute concurrent builds if necessary` option in your job configuration and then you will be able to run your job simultaneously on all available nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer. We can also restrict the job to a particular node on which it should run.

For eg 
A setup of 3 servers(2 Linux and one windows )

1 Linux server acts as master
1 Linux server acts as node
1 window server as as node

If we have a job that needs to be run on the windows node you can go to the job configuration and restrict the job to run on that node using the node name or label.

Additionally, the no. of executes define the instances of the slave or master node that can be executed parallelly across different jobs.

For running same job you need to check the enable concurrent build option and assign a label having more than 1 nodes in it

Cheers,
Yash